# OctoberCMS 404 page custom URL for my 404 page

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-backend, october-partial

I am using OctoberCMS [Static Pages](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-pages) plugin in which I have created a **404 page** with my custom URL something like this http://localhost/my_website/home/content/error404 .

When I open this page, its working fine but when someone types URL which is not exists something like this http://localhost/my_website/whatever, it is not showing the 404 page which I have created.

Can someone guide me how can I set this page as my default 404 page? 
Also I have created a **partial** to set the content and I dragged and dropped this **snippet** into this **static page**.

Any suggestion or thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create a page with the "URL" of the page in October set as `/404` and October will use it for 404 errors.

You can also set a page with a URL of `/error` to handle "500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: I just need to ask is octobercms has only capable of setting two types of errors ???
1.404 [by creating a page with /404 url ]
2.500 [by creating a page with /error url ]

how can we set 401, 402, 403 etc ??????